# Route for mailer link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, railstutorial.org

**Account activation**

The route and mailer link that I use for account account activation are as follows:

```
# Route:
resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]

# Link in mailer:    
<%= edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, email: @user.email) %>
```

The link generates a link such as `http://www.example.com/account_activations/q5lt38hQDc_959PVoo6b7A/edit?email=foo%40example.com`. The controller method uses the email address to find the user.

**Something similar for updating an email address**

Now I want to do something similar with a confirmation link if a user changes its email address. I've set up various controller and model methods but I think it's going wrong with regard to the link in the mailer and the route. I have:

```
# Route (should be the same as edit route above, but now for update_email):
get 'account_activations/update_email/:email' => 'account_activations#update_email', as: 'update_email'

# Link in mailer:
<%= update_email_url(@user.activation_token, email: @user.email) %>
```

**The problem:**

The link should identify the user based on its email address (just like for account activation) and generate a link such as: `http://www.example.com/account_activations/q5lt38hQDc_959PVoo6b7A/update_email?email=foo%40example.com`. Instead however it now generates a link such as `http://www.example.com/account_activations/update_email/foo@example.com`.

I think it's the route that is wrong, but am unsure how to 'mimick' the edit route that I have for account activations.

**Attempted alternative routes:**

- `get 'account_activations/update_email/:id' => 'account_activations#update_email', as: 'update_email'`. Here I get an error saying `missing required keys: [:id]`.
- `get 'account_activations/update_email' => 'account_activations#update_email', as: 'update_email'`. Here I get a link such `http://www.example.com/account_activations/update_email?email=foo%40example.com`. So again the token is missing from the link.
- `resources :account_activations, only: :update`. And changed the link to `<%= account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, email: @user.email) %>` (and of course change the method name in the controller). This produces the error message `No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"account_activations", :email=>"example@example.com", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]`.
- `get 'account_activations/:token/update_email' => 'account_activations#update_email', as: 'update_email'`. This generated the error `missing required keys: [:token]`.

**Update:**

If I use the route:

```
get 'account_activations/:id/update_email' => 'account_activations#update_email', as: 'update_email'
```

the two seem to be similar according to `rake routes`:

```
edit_account_activation GET    /account_activations/:id/edit(.:format)         account_activations#edit
           update_email GET    /account_activations/:id/update_email(.:format) account_activations#update_email
```

The to me it seems I then have the same situation as with "account activations". However, while this works for "account activations", for updating the email, when the mailer should send the link, it produces the error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"update_email", :controller=>"account_activations", :email=>"example@example.com", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Comment: What's wrong with `resources :account_activations, only: [:update]`?

Comment: Although not the case in my situation, I can imagine that one might already be using `update` for something else. But since that's not the case in my situation I tried it (added to original post as 3rd attempt). It might also be a problem that update does not generate a GET route.

Comment: Try this routes`get 'account_activations/:token/update_email' => 'account_activations#update_email', as: 'update_email'`

Comment: That generates the error `missing required keys: [:token]`. The token should be available as `params[:id]`, i.e., [railstutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation_password_reset#sec-account_activation_mailer) (which I followed for the account activations link) writes: "the token will be available in the params hash as params[:id].", which is why perhaps the first alternative I mention in the original post would make most sense.

Comment: for your update, try this `get '/account_activations/:id/update_email' => 'account_activations#update_email', as: 'update_email'`

Comment: Yes, then I do get the correct result for `rake routes` (added to OP) but when the mailer should send its message the link produces the error "missing required keys: [:id]".

Comment: Its not a solution, But  try like this, ` update_email_url(id: @user.activation_token, email: @user.email) `

Comment: Thanks Jon, the route mentioned in the update of the original post and that you mentioned as well, worked. It turned out there was an additional problem with a before action in the model file. This resulted in the token not being generated, which produced the error of the missing required key. But it's solved now.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having the same trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `get 'account_activations/update_email/:id' => 'account_activations#update_email', as: 'update_email'`. Here I get an error saying missing required keys: [:id].

You are getting this error because in your **config/routes.rb** file, you are saying `get 'account_activations/update_email/:id`, and that makes it necessary to send an `id` whenever you would trigger this route. And you when you do not send an `id`, you will get the error.

> `get 'account_activations/update_email' => 'account_activations#update_email', as: 'update_email'.` Here I get a link such `http://www.example.com/account_activations/update_email?email=foo%40example.com.` So again the token is missing from the link.

If you *really* want to send the token along with the request, you have to mention it in `get 'account_activations/update_email'` like `get 'account_activations/update_email/:token'`, this way - it will get appended with the URL.

> `resources :account_activations, only: :update`. And changed the link to `<%= account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, email: @user.email) %>` (and of course change the method name in the controller). This produces the error message:
>
> > No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"account_activations", :email=>"example@example.com", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id].

Well, this is what I explained you in the comment. `update` method does require the `id` of the model that you are trying to update. Without `id`, it won't work.

So, at the end - the solution that I'd suggest is: Make a custom method with the `get` route, and send token and `id` attached with the URL.

Comment: I believe `params[:id]` doesn't refer to the id of the user but to the token. [Railstutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation_password_reset#sec-account_activation_mailer) (which I used for account activations link) writes: "the token will be available in the params hash as params[:id].". In the end, I want to do the same for `update_email` as I do for "account activation" and currently I don't see why what I'm doing is working for account activation but not for updating the email address. The only difference I see is the route, why it seems to me there must be the cause

Comment: The author is saying, `as params[:id]`. If you write `get 'account_activations/:token/update_email'`, then you can access it through only `params[:token]`. To access it through `params[:id]`, you need to access to do `get 'account_activations/:id/update_email'`

Comment: Yes I think that's the route I'm looking for (added at the end of OP). Unfortunately, it still produces the error "missing required keys: [:id]". Really strange since it is working for "account activations" and I don't see how what I'm doing for update_email is any different.

Comment: You need to pass `id` in the URL that you are not passing.

Comment: Can you show me the URL that you are trying to access?

Comment: And if you do not want to want to pass the `id`, change your route to `account_activations/update_email/:token`, and just pass the token.

Comment: I'd prefer to keep the route as you previously suggested because I want it to be the same as I have for "account activation". The logic/url is similar to "account activation" as well: 1) user updates profile incl. email address, which calls on `def update` in user controller. 2) This method calls on a user model method that activates the mailer. 3) A before action generates the digest and token (private method). 4) The mailer sends the link. So it's an update button instead of an URL that activates this whole process.

Comment: So I wonder if perhaps when Rails says `:id=>nil`, that it's actually saying that the token has not been generated. Is there a way to check for this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79538/discussion-between-arslan-ali-and-nick).